# How to adjust the height of the row in a table automatically when having long text in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a simple table in Jasper Report with two columns. I am facing a problem that  sometime when a row in the table having a very long text, it will continue printing to the next line but the distance between this row and the next row are not changing. So as user I will see that these two rows are quite closed to each other, something like:

```
Column 1      Column2
--------      --------

Data1         Data2

Dataaaaaaaaa  Data4
aaaa3
Data5         Data6
```

Actually Data1, Data3 and Data5 are 3 data rows in my table but because Data3 is a very long text so it will be printed in next line also which is quite closed to Data5.

How can I adjust the hight of the row here automatically? I did tried to set the **Stretch Type** of the table to **Related To Talles Object** or **Related To Band Hight** but still not success.

Anyone has an idea? Thank you very much in advanced

Answer (score 0):

set the top and bottom cell padding

```
<box topPadding="5" bottomPadding="5"/>
```